# lynx blocked by google asking to fill captcha

Tags: linux, google-search, lynx

I was using lynx to dump search pages. But after about 20 requests, google blocked me asking to fill a captcha. But as I cant see image in lynx, I couldn't fill the captcha. Is there a way in which i can get google to unblock me?

I tried changing user agent in lynx.

Comment: Isn’t the reason for CAPTCHA to prevent automated dumps?

Comment: yes, but now i cant even do normal browsing using lynx

Answer (score 3):

Google will **unblock automatically, after a while**. After google detects much lesser activities, it will lift the ban. You may want to wait until few minutes, or even hours, which is not practical IMO. Manually answers the CAPTCHA will lift the ban. But if run lynx and hit 100 hits per second again, CAPTCHA will appear.

The important thing is how to make sure Lynx activities are not detected.

Human browsing activities are different than a program. We google 1st second and spend 10 seconds to some minutes to read the results and google again. Programs do not do that. Programs can send 10 to 100 hits per second, which google easily identified as machines.

There are few solutions that I can think of:

1. Use other search engines.
2. Create an sh script to **execute Lynx randomly**. This is to make the
       script behaves as human as possible, e.g. 1st second for 1st page,
       wait for 15 seconds. Next is the second page, but wait for 20
       seconds.
3. Use VPN. improve shell script above to inform you when captcha was
       triggered. When it is triggered,  it is time to use VPN to access google. When you are using VPN, your IP address changes, therefore it is assumed other users are browsing.